# How to collapse spaces between tags

Tags: regex

Let's say I have a language called "MyTagLanguage". Here is how the language is structured:

```
{myTag}
    some Info
{/myTag}
```

It looks similar to xml in structure, but it's not.

I need to minify this to remove whitespaces between the text and tags (but not affect the text itself). Here is how it should look:

```
{myTag}some Info{/myTag}
```

Here is the regular expression I have right now for it:

```
(?<=})\s+(?={)
```

However I think it can be improved significantly. What would be a regex for this?

Comment: Any good reason why it's _not_ an XML then? :) Also, per rules of [tag:regex] tag, you should also tag with a specific regex engine in mind.

Comment: @Amadan because if I do post a question with xml, then people close it immediately (without reading it) and say "you shouldn't parse xml with regex!", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex will only find spaces between two braces, such as `{myTag}  {/myTag}` or `{myTag}  {anotherTag}`, but not in the case you quoted (with `some Info` there).

This one should work though (Ruby syntax):

```
find:    (\{[^\/}]+\})\s+|\s+(?=\{\/[^\/}]*\})
replace: \1
```

Demo:

```
text = <<END
{myBigTag}
    {myTag}
        some Info
    {/myTag}
{/myBigTag}
END

text.gsub(/(\{[^\/}]+\})\s+|\s+(?=\{\/[^\/}]*\})/, '\1')
# => "{myBigTag}{myTag}some Info{/myTag}{/myBigTag}\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* take the approach of trying to match complete tags, and then strip off the whitespace you don't want:

```
Find:    \{([^}]+?)\}\s*([^{]+?)\s*\{/\1\}
Replace: {$1}$2{/$1}
```

### Demo

I chose the language "could" here because while my answer works on your exact input text, it could easily fail should you have tags which are nested more than one level deep.  In general, regex is not suitable for parsing nested content.

Comment: Upvote for acknowledging that regex is underpowered for parsing nested content, [be it XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60610187/290085) or "MyTagLanguage" (sigh).